# How to use MySQL instead of XML in this example.

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I was looking for tutorials on how to create " Ajax auto suggest " script for our company's phone booking system. I work for my uncle in cars re-selling company, and I really need to crate this script for my boss. I well about HTML, CSS and have average knowledge about PHP and MYSQL. I've actually create a search system but, I found this

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp 
tutorial on how to create a live search. The only problem is that, they use XML, and that is complete chines to me.  So, instead of using XML to store the data of our phonebooks, I would like to use mysql instead.

Is this possible at all? if so, any link/suggestion would be really nice.

thanks

Comment: What about google? something like "php mysql live search"? Did it return anything useful?

Comment: What prevents you from turning a Mysql response into XML?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to run before you can walk: first, write a simple search form which you submit and it runs some `SQL` to find the right results.

Once that's done, all a "live search" requires is JavaScript that quietly submits the form while you're typing and shows the top few results in an appropriate way.

You may also want to look at an auto-complete plugin, such as this one: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Again, write the code to search your database first, then adapt it to fit what the JavaScript needs.

Comment: Most things will work fine on iPhone/iPad the safari browser on iOS is quite capable (in some cases superior to a popular desktop browser ;))